# Getting a UIColor from a restricted range in the HSB spectrum

Tags: ios, uicolor

I want to use just a portion of the hue spectrum (from yellowish-green to red only) to indicate a state change specified by a calculated float value.

I found it was easy enough to use the entire spectrum:

```
float hue;
hue = (1.0 * [c floatValue]);

float saturation;
saturation = 1.0;

float alpha;
alpha =  1.0;

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue
                            saturation:saturation
                            brightness:1.0
                                 alpha:alpha];

NSLog(@"color %@",color);


self.backgroundBar.backgroundColor = color;
```

But I don't want all those other colors.

`c` is a float value between 0.00 and 1.0

How can I restrict the sweep to the range between yellowish-green (hue = 75/255) and red (hue = 15/255)?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to map a value between 0 and 1 to a value between 0.05 and 0.35 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Those values don't seem to match...

Comment: But generally, I think we're on the same page if I understand the mapping idea.

Comment: Those are roughly your values red to greenish done in my head.  So `mapped = c * ( green - red)  + red`

Comment: Ah, ok. I've shut the MBP down for the night but will give it a whirl in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: @WarrenBurton--works like a charm, with the addition of a decimal point in the original values! If you'd care to formalize the solution in an answer, I'll be pleased to upvote it. Rashad suggested essentially the same thing, but your solution arrived first. Thanks!!!

Comment: its cool , if the answer is what you want accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wanted to have a range between 15/255 to 75 / 255, that means if the value of `c` is 0 it hue will be 15/255 and if `c` is  1 then hue 75/255.

Let,

```
low = 15.f/255.f;
high = 75.f/255.f;
```

So, hue should be,

```
hue = c* (high - low) + low;
```

Comment: Many thanks, Rashad! I would note that that I had to change 15/255 to 15.0/255 to get it to work properly. Otherwise, works perfectly! Thanks again!